# Real Time Object detection using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-recognition, tensorboard

I have just started experimenting with Deep Learning and Computer Vision technologies. I came across this awesome [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/). I have setup the TensorFlow environment using docker and trained my own sets of objects and it provided greater accuracy when I tested it out.

Now I want to make the same more real-time. For example, instead of giving an image of an object as the input, I want to utilize a webcam and make it recognize the object with the help of TensorFlow. Can you guys guide me with the right place to start with this work?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [TensorFlow Serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/) so that you can decouple compute from sensors (and distribute the computation), or our [C++ api](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/cc/index.html). Beyond that, tensorflow was written emphasizing throughput rather than latency, so batch samples as much as you can. You don't need to run tensorflow at every frame, so input from a webcam should definitely be in the realm of possibilities. Making the network smaller, and buying better hardware are popular options.

Comment: I thought TensorFlow Serving might be required. But for that we need to export our model in the first place, right? How can I export the model that I have retrained using TensorFlow (with the help  of the Tutorial I mentioned in the question)?

Comment: Yes, you can just export that, then the tensorflow server will be able to run the model on your input tensors.

Comment: That's the question. How can I export the model? I got a .pb file as an output. What should I do?

Comment: You should have gotten a checkpoint, if following [the instructions](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic).